# Mezclar en una lista numros comunes y no comunes dentro del intervalo marcado por la primera lista

Tags: c#, algoritmos, lista, ordenamiento

Buenas, he replanteado la cuestión

tengo una lista:

> [-0.5 , -0.4 , -0.1 , 0 , 1.0 , 2.0 , 3.0 , 2.0 , 1.0 , 0 , -0.2 , -0.3 -0.5]

y otra lista:

> [-0.3 , -0.1 , 0 , 1.2 , 2.0 , 2.3 , 2.0 , 1.5 , 0 , -0.1 , -0.3 -0.5]

el resultado final debe ser la mezcla de estas dos manteniendo el orden:

> [-0.5 , -0.4 , -0.3 , -0.1 , 0 , 1.0 , 1.2 , 2.0 , 2.3 , 3.0 , 2.0 , 1.0 , 0 , -0.1 , -0.2 , -0.3 , -0.5]

Estos valores correspondes a valor de coordenada X, es un curva de ida y vuelta

> -n, ... , 0 , ... , n , ... , 0 , ... , -n

```
 int contadorA = 0;
        int contadorB = 0;
        double extremoIzquierdo = lListaAOriginal[0].CoordenadaX;
        double extremoDerecho = lListaAOriginal[lListaAOriginal.Count - 1].CoordenadaX;
        /*
        foreach (Dato daux in lListaBOriginal.ToList())
        {
            if (daux.CoordenadaX < 0)
            {
                if (daux.CoordenadaX < extremoIzquierdo)
                {
                    lListaBOriginal.Remove(daux);
                }
            }
            if (daux.CoordenadaX > 0)
            {
                if (daux.CoordenadaX > extremoIzquierdo)
                {
                    lListaBOriginal.Remove(daux);
                }
            }
        }*/

        Dato primeroA = lListaAOriginal[0];

        List<Dato> lista1Ascendente = new List<Dato>();
        lista1Ascendente.Add(primeroA);
        List<Dato> lista1Descendente = new List<Dato>();
        int contador = 0;
        foreach (Dato daux in lListaAOriginal.ToList())
        {
            if (daux.CoordenadaX > primeroA.CoordenadaX)
            {
                lista1Ascendente.Add(daux);
                primeroA = daux;
                contador++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = contador+1; i <= lListaAOriginal.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            lista1Descendente.Add(lListaAOriginal[i]);
        }



        Dato primeroB = lListaBOriginal[0];

        List<Dato> lista2Ascendente = new List<Dato>();
        lista2Ascendente.Add(primeroB);
        List<Dato> lista2Descendente = new List<Dato>();
        contador = 0;
        foreach (Dato daux in lListaBOriginal.ToList())
        {
            if (daux.CoordenadaX > primeroB.CoordenadaX)
            {
                lista2Ascendente.Add(daux);
                primeroB = daux;
                contador++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = contador + 1; i <= lListaBOriginal.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            lista2Descendente.Add(lListaBOriginal[i]);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i <= lista1Ascendente.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= lista2Ascendente.Count - 1; j++)
            {

                if (lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX < lista2Ascendente[j].CoordenadaX)
                {

                    if (!lista1Ascendente[i].Error1)
                    {
                        nuevaListaA.Add(lista1Ascendente[i]);
                        lista1Ascendente[i].Error1 = true;
                        auxDato = new Dato();
                        if (lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX < lista2Ascendente[0].CoordenadaX)
                        {
                            auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((lista2Ascendente[1].CoordenadaY - lista2Ascendente[0].CoordenadaY) / (lista2Ascendente[1].CoordenadaX - lista2Ascendente[0].CoordenadaX))
                                * (lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX - lista2Ascendente[0].CoordenadaX) + lista2Ascendente[0].CoordenadaY;
                            auxDato.CoordenadaX = lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((lista2Ascendente[j].CoordenadaY - lista2Ascendente[j - 1].CoordenadaY) / (lista2Ascendente[j].CoordenadaX - lista2Ascendente[j - 1].CoordenadaX))
                                * (lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX - lista2Ascendente[j - 1].CoordenadaX) + lista2Ascendente[j - 1].CoordenadaY;
                            auxDato.CoordenadaX = lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX;
                        }
                        nuevaListaB.Add(auxDato);
                    }


                }
                else if (lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX > lista2Ascendente[j].CoordenadaX)
                {

                    if (!lista2Ascendente[j].Error1)
                    {
                        auxDato = new Dato();
                        auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaY - lista1Ascendente[i - 1].CoordenadaY) / (lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX - lista1Ascendente[i - 1].CoordenadaX))
                        * (lista2Ascendente[j].CoordenadaX - lista1Ascendente[i - 1].CoordenadaX) + lista1Ascendente[i - 1].CoordenadaY;
                        auxDato.CoordenadaX = lista2Ascendente[j].CoordenadaX;
                        nuevaListaA.Add(auxDato);

                        nuevaListaB.Add(lista2Ascendente[j]);
                        lista2Ascendente[j].Error1 = true;
                    }


                }
                else if (lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX == lista2Ascendente[j].CoordenadaX)
                {
                    if (!lista2Ascendente[j].Error1 && !lista1Ascendente[i].Error1)
                    {
                        lista2Ascendente[j].Error1 = true;
                        lista1Ascendente[i].Error1 = true;
                        nuevaListaA.Add(lista1Ascendente[i]);
                        nuevaListaB.Add(lista2Ascendente[j]);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    nuevaListaA.Add(lista1Ascendente[i]);
                    lista1Ascendente[i].Error1 = true;
                    auxDato = new Dato();
                    auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 1].CoordenadaY - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaY) / (nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 1].CoordenadaX - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaX))
                                    * (lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaX) + nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaY;
                    auxDato.CoordenadaX = lista1Ascendente[i].CoordenadaX;

                    nuevaListaB.Add(auxDato);
                }




            }

        }


        for (int i = 0; i <= lista1Descendente.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= lista2Descendente.Count - 1; j++)
            {

                if (lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX > lista2Descendente[j].CoordenadaX)
                {

                    if (!lista1Descendente[i].Error1)
                    {
                        nuevaListaA.Add(lista1Descendente[i]);
                        lista1Descendente[i].Error1 = true;
                        auxDato = new Dato();
                        if (lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX < lista2Descendente[0].CoordenadaX)
                        {
                            auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((lista2Descendente[1].CoordenadaY - lista2Descendente[0].CoordenadaY) / (lista2Descendente[1].CoordenadaX - lista2Descendente[0].CoordenadaX))
                                * (lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX - lista2Descendente[0].CoordenadaX) + lista2Descendente[0].CoordenadaY;
                            auxDato.CoordenadaX = lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((lista2Descendente[j].CoordenadaY - lista2Descendente[j - 1].CoordenadaY) / (lista2Descendente[j].CoordenadaX - lista2Descendente[j - 1].CoordenadaX))
                            //    * (lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX - lista2Descendente[j - 1].CoordenadaX) + lista2Descendente[j - 1].CoordenadaY;
                            auxDato.CoordenadaX = lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX;
                        }
                        nuevaListaB.Add(auxDato);
                    }


                }
                else if (lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX < lista2Descendente[j].CoordenadaX)
                {

                    if (!lista2Descendente[j].Error1)
                    {
                        auxDato = new Dato();
                        auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaY - lista1Descendente[i - 1].CoordenadaY) / (lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX - lista1Descendente[i - 1].CoordenadaX))
                        * (lista2Descendente[j].CoordenadaX - lista1Descendente[i - 1].CoordenadaX) + lista1Descendente[i - 1].CoordenadaY;
                        auxDato.CoordenadaX = lista2Descendente[j].CoordenadaX;
                        nuevaListaA.Add(auxDato);
                        nuevaListaB.Add(lista2Descendente[j]);
                        lista2Descendente[j].Error1 = true;
                    }


                }
                else if (lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX == lista2Descendente[j].CoordenadaX)
                {
                    if (!lista2Descendente[j].Error1 && !lista1Descendente[i].Error1)
                    {
                        lista2Descendente[j].Error1 = true;
                        lista1Descendente[i].Error1 = true;
                        nuevaListaA.Add(lista1Descendente[i]);
                        nuevaListaB.Add(lista2Descendente[j]);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    nuevaListaA.Add(lista1Descendente[i]);
                    lista1Descendente[i].Error1 = true;
                    auxDato = new Dato();
                    auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 1].CoordenadaY - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaY) / (nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 1].CoordenadaX - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaX))
                                    * (lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaX) + nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaY;
                    auxDato.CoordenadaX = lista1Descendente[i].CoordenadaX;

                    nuevaListaB.Add(auxDato);
                }




            }

        }

        foreach (Dato daux in lista1Descendente.ToList())
        {
            if (!daux.Error1)
            {
                nuevaListaA.Add(daux);
                daux.Error1 = true;
                auxDato = new Dato();
                auxDato.CoordenadaY = ((nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 1].CoordenadaY - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaY) / (nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 1].CoordenadaX - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaX))
                                * (daux.CoordenadaX - nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaX) + nuevaListaB[nuevaListaB.Count - 2].CoordenadaY;
                auxDato.CoordenadaX = daux.CoordenadaX;

                nuevaListaB.Add(auxDato);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola BeginnerDeveloper. Por favor, evita abrir mas de una pregunta para la misma cosa. Si deseas aclarar-modificar tu pregunta original, eso está bien.

Answer (score 0):

Este problema puedes solucionarlo facilmente con un algoritmo de tipo "Mergesort".

El algoritmo suele utilizarse para ordenar listas desordenadas, y lo que haces es primero separar la lista en trozos, y luego unirlos manteniendo el orden.

Para tu problema tendrás que tocar un poco el algoritmo de modo que te respete que la lista primero es ascendente y luego descendente.

Yo que tú, dividiría cada lista en 2 partes, Lista1Ascendente, Lista1Descendente, Lista2Ascendente y Lista2Descendente. Con eso, mezclo las dos listas ascendentes y las dos descendentes, quedandome con una sola lista ascendente y una sola lista descendente. Entonces simplemente concatenas una lista con la otra y tienes tu solución.

Comment: lol así lo hice, el ultimo foreach es para meter los que no hay XD, me he quedado alucinado porque usé los mismo nombre que has puesto tu
Si se te ocurre alguna mejor espacio temporal...